# Can sharding help in this scenario?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, sharding

I will have around 600 GB of data in single table with multiple columns in MySQL. Basically this table will store user events from application. 
Indexes are there on required columns.

Question: If I shard the data based on some key which will be included  in every  query,
insertion and selection will happen on limited data set. Say I have 3 nodes  and data is redistributed equally on all 3 nodes with each shard of 200 GB.
Now based on shard key in query, I will send it to specific DB only.I think it will improve the search performance. Is that right ?

**Constraint :** Issue is I have single node. If create three shards(of 200 GB each) on single node , will it help in search performance ?

Can MongoDB(instead of MYSQL) help here with same approach ?

Comment: Do you have a performance problem now?  Will a 'search' go to only one shard?  What are you searching on (FULLTEXT / combination of columns / numeric or string / etc)?

Comment: Yes I have performance issues. At present there is single DB/shard. I am searching on combination of multiple columns which can be numeric/text/date etc Can you please answer it now ?

Comment: Show us a few typical queries.  Is the search open-ended; that is, can the user create any sort of query on a lot of columns?  What column would you shard on?  Is that column always part of the queries you get?

Comment: It sounds like the data is bigger than RAM.  So, after sharding, the shards will be competing for I/O, and you will be I/O-bound.  No benefit in sharding unless you have multiple _machines_.

Comment: I will select a column based on which data is equally distributed among shards. Yes that column will also be part of queries. Not sure on what reasoning you are saying that `It sounds like the data is bigger than RAM`.  Even if it is true how come `after sharding, the shards will be competing for I/O, and I will be I/O-bound` ?

Comment: Each of the 3 shards on the same hardware will have only 1/3 the RAM.  Hence, less caching ability for the smaller amount of data.  That is, If it is I/O-bound before sharding, it still will be afterward.  And since, I/O is effectively single-threaded (only one way to get to disk), there will be little speed increase.

Comment: On the other hand, if the data were small enough to be cached, then the processing would be CPU-bound, and you probably have multiple cores.  Hence 3 shards might come close to 3x speedup.  (Ignoring the effort it takes to combine the 3 sets of results.)

Comment: Do you have a terabyte of RAM?

Comment: You said  `And since, I/O is effectively single-threaded (only one way to get to disk), there will be little speed increase` I believe speed will be lesser or same in fact as there be context switching for I/O coming from diff shards ? Second point you said `if the data were small enough to be cached, then the processing would be CPU-bound`   which cache you are talking about ? Is it default MySQL buffer cache or some explicit caching ? Also will access from cache be CPU -bound operation ? I have 16 GB of ram only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If create three shards(of 200 GB each) on single node, will it help in search performance ?

**Short Answer**: No.

**Info from Comments**:

16GB of RAM.

The important query is a "search", but it is rather unbounded.  Hence, we need to assume that the whole table (600GB) needs to be scanned.

So, why not have multiple instances of MySQL, each with a fraction of the data?  They could work in parallel, couldn't they?

**Long Answer**:

I/O is much more costly (10x?  100x?) than CPU or context switching or looking a cache.  Of the 16GB, you will allocate perhaps 11GB for  `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, which is the main "cache" in MySQL.  There is no way to fit 600GB into 11GB, so there will be I/O.  If you shard across ~60 *separate* machines, then you could avoid I/O.  Or if you had 700GB of RAM on the one machine.

So, on a single machine, the parallelism is defeated because of there being only one access to disk, and each parallel thread need to spend most of its time fetching data from disk.  You would see the CPU cores sitting there twiddling their thumbs waiting for I/O.

**What if an index could be used?**

Why bother with sharding?  With a *usable* index, the query is likely to be fast because it won't be touching much of the 600GB, hence doing very little I/O.

And if you have lots of *different* connections, MySQL (with the help of the OS) is happy to farm them out to different CPUs.

Hence, I/O is not a bottleneck; CPU is not a bottleneck?  The sharded system is complex, but for no benefit.

**When is Sharding needed?**

If you need "read scaling" -- that is, too many clients are accessing MySQL, and the system is overloaded -- use Replication.  Each Slave has a copy of the data.  You can add as many Slaves as needed to handle the load.  Note:  Each Slave needs to be on its own hardware.

If you need "write scaling" -- that is, the writes, not the reads, are the bottleneck -- then you might need multiple servers and do "sharding".

Even with either of those situations, I suggest that there may be ways to improve the performance of the queries / indexes / ETL / etc to tame it.

Comment: You sais `And if you have lots of different connections, MySQL (with the help of the OS) is happy to farm them out to different CPUs.`
But CPU has very liitle role here . Say my query is select coun(1) from user_profile where column_1='xyz' and column_2='abc' 
row will be accessed from disk and keepon incrementing the counter. Per mine understanding CPU has very limited role here in just incrementing
the counter. Is n't it ?

Comment: @user3198603 - If all the data happens to be cached in RAM (innodb_buffer_pool), then the counting involves the CPU and not I/O.

Comment: Got it. But first time when query is executed, one row will be fetched at time from disk then counting happens. For consecutive execution of same query, if all data is in cache then yes it will be only CPU. Right ?

Comment: @user3198603 - _Blocks_ (16KB each) are cached.  If you are counting (or fetching) "consecutive" rows, then perhaps 100 rows will be fetched from one block before needing to fetch the next block from disk.  Correct - If the entire table (or the index being used) is cached on the first scan, the second execution of the same query will be CPU-bound.  I recommend people time a query twice -- the first does any I/O that might be needed; the second is 'realistic' for a 'production' environment.

Comment: @user3198603 - And...  If the table (or index) is too big for the buffer pool, even the second execution will be I/O-bound, hence slow.  In both scenarios, the second timing is the useful one.

Comment: I believe  Blocks (16KB each) are cached only when they data under that block is accesed not at the time of writing ? So it will be read thru cache not write thru cache

Comment: Writing involves placing a row into a block.  That is done via read-modify-write.  That is, any kind of write (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) involves first making sure the block is in the buffer_pool.  After modifying, the block is left in the buffer_pool, but will eventually be written to disk.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/237949/where-mysql-is-taking-time-either-in-disk-read-or-computation ?

Answer (score 0):

> Constraint: I have a single node. If create three shards(of 200 GB
>   each) on a single node, will it help in search performance?

Yes, definitely it will improve your search performance. In a clustered deployment, queries can run in parallel and speed up the query response time. As you mentioned in your question you will be selecting the shard key that will be used in all your search queries, since this is a targeted query you will see a lot of improvement in the read performance.

> Can MongoDB(instead of MYSQL) help here with the same approach?

Yes, MongoDB will be a perfect choice for this requirement. MongoDB supports horizontal scaling from out of the box.

Refer to the official documentation for [Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#advantages-of-sharding).

Comment: What about the constraint I have mentioned in question ?

Comment: Don't forget that you need to combine the results from each shard.