# Where MySQL is taking time either in disk read or computation?

Tags: mysql, rdbms, cpu

From [SQl case study](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/07/increasing-slow-query-performance-with-parallel-query-execution/)

System configuration is

`Software: Percona 5.6.15-63.0. Hardware: Supermicro; X8DTG-D; 48G of RAM; 24xIntel(R) Xeon(R) CPU L5639 @ 2.13GHz, 1xSSD drive (250G)`

Query is `select yeard, count(*) from ontime group by yeard` where yeard is indexed column

The query is simple, however, it will have to scan 150M rows. Here is the results of the query (cached):
`The query took 54 seconds and utilized only 1 CPU core`

My understanding :- Per my calculation it should have finished in much less time based on above system shared configuration and data to scan.
I know I am wrong and missing something but what is that ?

Here is my calculation for seconds

1. For HDD,  average time taken to read 100MB of data from disk is around 1 sec. For SSD is 5 to 10X faster. But still conservatively if I assume the speed of
   100MB per seconds , time to  read the data will be `size of data in MB/100` seconds . Based on this size of data is `150 * 10^6 * 4/10^6= 600 MB`
   assuming each year is of 4 byte long. So total time to read the data from disk should be `600/100 = 6 secs`
2. Now it 2.13GHz CPU which means that 2 billion cycles per seconds which on average means 2 billion instruction per second per core. Now  actual
   time taken to execute the query was 54 seconds which means time taken to compute the instruction was approx `54-6 = 48 seconds`. Does it mean to  it had to execute  around `48 * 2 = 96 billion instructions` just to calculate
   the count and group by year or am I missing something ?

May be more time in disk read or count looks simple but internally it involves number of instructions ?

Comment: You're not just doing a `count(*)`, you're doing a `group by`, which is more expensive. Anyway, for starters, edit your question with an explain plan of the query

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ I agree there are two operation i.e `group by ` and then `count` but still do you think it will be close to 96 billion instructions. If i think it will be doing group by internally it will maintaining some kind of map(like HashMap in java) with key as year and value as count . Also the explain plan is given under the link I mentioned . I did not paste it here to avoid verbosity

Comment: Without proper instrumentation and actually measuring where the bottlenecks are, this question is impossible to answer I’m afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rule of Thumb:  If the necessary data is cached, the query will run 10x faster than if not.  I have seen this in a wide variety of queries.  (Of course, the "10" varies a lot, too.)

Assuming

```
 SELECT yeard, COUNT(*) FROM t GROUP BY yeard;

 INDEX(yeard)
```

The Optimizer will scan the entire `INDEX(yeard)` of 150M 'rows'.  It does not have to do much more (at a high level) than count rows until `yeard` changes.  That is the `INDEX` and the `GROUP BY` work well together; they are not two separate steps.

- About 400 index entries per 16KB block.
- 100 blocks/second is a more realistic estimate for InnoDB hitting HDD.  (This goes away for any blocks that are cached.)
- 150M/400/100 = 3750 seconds.  So, 54s for SSD seems about optimistic.  Or some of the blocks were cached.

If you run the query a second time (after all the blocks are cached), it may run 10x faster.

It's hard to say how many CPU cycles a query will take.  The code to "get the next row" (even of an index) is somewhat generic, and meanwhile, it is building (probably) an in-memory hash of the results.  There are also steps to parse the query, decide how to optimize it, deliver the results, etc.

The `EXPLAIN` in this example will say "Using index", meaning that it *only* used the index's BTree and did not need to touch the data's BTree.

The BTree is really a B+Tree, meaning that consecutive blocks are linked, making linear scans (as with your query) efficient.

Comment: As you said `The Optimizer will scan the entire INDEX(yeard) of 150M 'rows'. It does not have to do much more (at a high level) than count rows until yeard changes` so you are saying majority of the 54 secs will utilized in disk scan not in computing like count and group by . Is that right ?

Comment: Other couple of observations `Point-1` you said "About 400 index entries per 16KB block" I believe assumption is 40B for each year ?
`Point-2` you said "100 blocks/second is a more realistic estimate for InnoDB hitting HDD" This means it will 16*100KB per second i.e 1.6 MB per sec.
Per my reading , on an average OS can read 100MB per sec from HDD . Is not that correct ? `Point-3` you said "150M/400/100 = 3750 seconds. So, 54s for SSD seems about optimistic. " This means  read speed of SSD is 70 times faster than HDD  ?

Comment: @user3198603 - Most of the numbers I mentioned are subject to critique.  Some are from experience -- every few months I see some data which feeds into, say, the 100 hits/sec.  Note how many things are hidden behind that -- caching, conflicting activity, arm motion, 16KB is 32 disk sectors, blocks might not be consecutively placed, etc, etc.  The 400 comes from estimating the size of that index, adding overhead for each 'row', adding overhead for the way a BTree works, etc.  I did not even start with good raw data -- datatype of `yeard`, what is PK?

Comment: I totally understand these numbers are high level numbers and subject to critique. Can you please share your thoughts on my first comment and Point-2 and 3 as well ?

Comment: @user3198603 - **2** The OS may be able to _read_ 100MBs, but can the HDD (without RAID) _deliver_ that much.  Also, the 100MB is probably _sequential_, not _random_.  (OK, it is a stretch to get a factor of 60 discrepancy.)  **3** I don't have a good feel for the speed difference between HDD and SDD.  From InnoDB's perspective, there are other delays (OS, parsing, etc) that will keep InnoDB from seeing 70x even if the _raw_ hardware is 70x.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One last thing from your statement `The Optimizer will scan the entire INDEX(yeard) of 150M 'rows'. It does not have to do much more (at a high level) than count rows until yeard changes`, with this and other points we discussed above, I conclude that majority of time goes here in read the data from disk not in computation(like count and group by). Is that right ?

Comment: @user3198603 - Correct.  The only way to count the rows is to read them from disk (if not already cached in the buffer_pool).  It does get tricky -- if another connection is deleting rows (or inserting), should those rows be counted?  That depends on transaction_isolation_mode, etc.